# jQuery plugins work on localhost but not live

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, aurelia, easy-webpack

fairly new to web development here so please bear with me.

I am learning to build a new nodejs app using aurelia framework.

I used 2 jQuery plugins - fullPage.js and fancybox3.js - The first one to run a full page video background, and the second to add a lightbox gallery to my images.

They run just fine on localhost, but not live. I have no idea where to even begin to look to troubleshoot this.

I have the app deployed for the time being at https://northwavey-895da.firebaseapp.com , would be nice if anyone could share some tips..

Comment: Looks like your plugin files aren't being found: https://northwavey-895da.firebaseapp.com/lib/jquery.fullPage.js

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.fullPage.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.fancybox.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
/webpack-dev-server.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please share your JavaScript/HTML code with us so we can help you better?

Comment: something occurs is you route all js files to your homepage

Comment: There's somethings wrong in your server code. Post it pls.

Comment: Ok, if it's any help, I added my project here:  https://bitbucket.org/onionzerg/northwavey 
It seems webpack did not add my js files for fullPage and fancybox when building into the /dist folder. Checking it out...